# pie chart filter in power bi

Tags: powerbi, pie-chart, powerbi-filters

I have a problem in power bi. suppose I wanna have the pie chart of items thrn  I wanna apply the filter based on branches. when choosing a branch, the pie chart shows the items related to that branch. but now it shows the pie chart of the all branches and highlights the related part of the filtered branch.

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using Visuals value to filter Pie Chart data and this is expected. For example you have 10 rows in a table visual and you have a Pie Chart for that 10 same values. Now, you are selecting 1 row in the table visual and what happened in the table visual? 1 selected row is highlighted and other 9 rows become faded, right? The Pie chart also showing the same way and this is correct.

But, if you wants to filter out everything in the Pie chart based on your selection, you need to use **Slicer**. Just generate your slicer with the column you wants to filter data. Now select value in slicer and the Pie chart will also response accordingly.

Step-1: Create the Slicer with column "**Branch**"

Step-2: Create the Pie chart with Legend = "**Item**" and Value = "**your_value_column**"

When nothing is selected in the slicer, you will get results for all your items for all branches. But, when you select 1 or multiple values from the slicer, Item will be only belongs to those selected Branches.

Comment: Hi @Zahra, nice to see that it helped. You can also put an up vote :)